# How can I get Gulp to recognise changes/updates in compiled files?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I'm building a few sites and am using Gulp to compile their .scss files into a `main.css` file.

Things are working fine but for one thing - Gulp doesn't seem to know when `main.css` file has been updated.

For example, if I run `gulp sass` and compile my `main.css` file, then run my FTP deploy script, `gulp ftp-deploy`, the .scss files (and any other .html or .php files I've been working on) will deploy, but not the `main.css` file.

Gulp will only recognise if there is a change in `main.css` if I open it in my IDE, make an alteration like adding a space or something, then save.

The above problem also happens when I run Shopify ThemeKit's `theme watch` command as well.

Would anyone know how I could make it so changes are detected?

My gulpfile.js is as such:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass'); //Compiles SASS
const ftp = require( 'vinyl-ftp' ); //FTP

gulp.task('sass', function(){
  return gulp.src('scss/main.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
});

gulp.task('ftp-deploy', function() {

  var conn = ftp.create({
    // CONFIG
  });

  var localFilesGlob = ['css/**']; 

  return gulp.src(localFilesGlob, { base: '.', buffer: false })
    .pipe( conn.newer( '.' ) )
    .pipe( conn.dest( '.' ) )
  ;

});
```

**Additional info**

node.js version is 11.6.0

npm version is 6.5.0

Gulp version is 4.0.0 (2.0.1 CLI)

I on MacOS 10.14.2

Comment: This might need more info -- so far, it sounds like it is behaving exactly as it should.  If you edit an _scss_ file, gulp will recognize this and regenerate the corresponding _css_ file.  Note that you'll have to re-run `gulp sass` of course.  (Your gulpfile does not include a "watch" task, if your problem is with the watch task, you should include that code in your question.)

Comment: @ElliotNelson, yes the `gulp sass` command works fine - the .css is compiled with my changes to .scss. The problem is with `ftp-deploy`. It only recognises files are changed if I change them manually in my IDE (so it sees changes in the scss files but not the css file).

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I originally thought you were talking about some kind of `gulp watch` behavior; I missed that `newer` line in your `ftp-deploy`.

This sounds to me like a modification time comparison issue. This is often due to a *difference in time* between your local machine and the server (one or the other of you may be off by a few minutes, causing flaky behavior in your task). Another possibility is that the server is in a different timezone and uses local time instead of UTC. The answer to the S.O. question [Gulp Vinyl FTP Timezone Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45725528/gulp-vinyl-ftp-using-gulp-newer-is-not-noticing-changes-in-files-and-is-therefor) might help you there.

There should be no difference between hand-editing a file in `/css` and running `gulp sass` to regenerate them; all that matters is the modification time (run `ls -l css` to see that, so you know what is being looked at, and can compare it to the files on the server). One thing to be aware of is that just re-running `gulp sass` *without any changes to the SCSS files* will not update files in `/css` with new timestamps; that is a feature of gulp that might trip you up while you are testing.